# How do I plot coordinates on a US map?

Tags: r, maps, coordinates

I am new to R and have only gotten this far using tutorials. my data "geolocation" contains coordinates to about 200 cities in the US.

```
library("ggmap")
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")
library ("usmap")
library("ggplot2")
library("maps")


geolocation<-read.csv("mapdata.csv")
geolocation<-geolocation[,1:7]
names(geolocation)<-c("City","State","Country","Size","Status","Lat","Long")


map("state")


p <- ggmap(USA)
p <- p + geom_point(data=geolocation, aes(x= Long, y= Lat), size=Size, color=Status)
```

Comment: Seems like you have got to the stage of having points on a map. What is the issue you are having? Some kind of warning or error? Or you don't know how to view the map?

Comment: Did you try: 

p <- p + geom_point(data=geolocation, aes(x= Long, y= Lat), size=Size, color=Status, inherit.aes = FALSE)

Comment: I don't know your familiarity with `ggplot2`, so perhaps a too-simple question: have you looked at `p`? If not on the console, you'd need to include `print(p)` to actually render the graphic. (Sorry if that is too fundamental ... it's difficult sometimes to know if you are reducing code in your question or don't know that you need it.)

Comment: the error is here "Error in ggmap(USA) : object 'USA' not found" everything is fine until I try to create 'p' and add points to it. thank you all for your help!

Comment: if I change it to: # get map #
p <- map("state")

# plot data on map #
p+geom_point(data=geolocation, aes(x= Long, y= Lat))


then, "NULL" comes up?